# Can someone help me with ETSI/BRAN Indoor wireless channel specification and implementation in MATLAB

Tags: multi-channel

I want to implement ETSI/BRAN Indoor Model A channel, i have the delays for the paths tau=[0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 110 140 170 200 240 290 340 390]*10^(-9); and the Average Relative Power (dB) pdb=[0 -0.9 -1.7 -2.6 -3.5 -4.3 -5.2 -6.1 -6.9 -7.8 -4.7 -7.3 -9.9 -12.5 -13.7 -18 -22.4 -26.7]; and i want to create time varying channel using Mont Carlo Method (i have no idea about it), please help me how can i implement it in matlab

Comment: Hi! Welcome to DSP SE! We will do our best, but can you help us to help you and provide detailed informations where the problem lies, what you did so far, etc?

Comment: Thanks jojek; I want to do a realistic implementation of ETSI/BRAN Indoor Model A channel , i have the delays for the paths and the Average Relative Power (dB) and i want to create time varying channel

Comment: Please update your question accordingly with all the details.